# Making friend list invisible

Tags: facebook

How do I make my friend list invisible to my other friends on my facebook? I thought making my friend list private did the job. But it didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps.

> - Click the “Friends” button underneath your cover photo. This will  open a list of all of your friends.
> - Click the “Manage” button. This is the little square button next to    the “+Find Friends” button. It has a pencil icon on it.
> - Select “Edit Privacy”. This will open a new window where you can    adjust your privacy settings for your friends list.
> - Select your privacy options. Next to “Friend List”, click the    drop-down menu to see your privacy options. If you don’t want anyone  to see your friends list, select “Only Me”. You can also set it to a  custom setting, or to one of the lists you’ve created.

[Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Hide-Friends-on-Facebook).